# Handling `IO Bool` and `IO (Either a b)` inside `IO (Maybe b)`

Tags: haskell

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

data E a
  = E1
  | E2
  | E3 a

data L
data R

f :: IO (Maybe (E L))
f =
  (undefined :: IO Bool) >>= \case
    False -> return (Just E1)
    True  ->
      (undefined :: IO Bool) >>= \case
        False -> return (Just E2)
        True  ->
          (undefined :: IO (Either L R)) >>= \case
            Left e  -> return (Just (E3 e))
            Right v -> (undefined :: R -> IO ()) v >> return Nothing
```

How to get rid of these three nested `case`s?

Comment: In what context does this code appear? It looks very [hypothetical](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1709/9357), the way you have presented it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to abort your computation early and return a value different from the final output, the [`ExceptT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html) transformer would be useful.

```
import Control.Monad (unless)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except

data E a
  = E1
  | E2
  | E3 a

data L
data R

f :: ExceptT (E L) IO ()
f = do
  liftIO (undefined :: IO Bool) >>= flip unless (throwE E1)
  liftIO (undefined :: IO Bool) >>= flip unless (throwE E2)
  liftIO (undefined :: IO (Either L R)) >>=
    either (throwE . E3) (liftIO . (undefined :: R -> IO ()))
```

If we want, we can then convert `ExceptT (E L) IO ()` to `IO (Maybe (E L))`:

```
f' :: IO (Maybe (E L))
f' = either Just (const Nothing) <$> runExceptT f
```

If could be further polished by using helper functions from [`Control.Conditional`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cond-0.4.0.2/docs/Control-Conditional.html#v:unlessM) or a similar library, and by extending the functions, for which `undefined` fills in, to work within any [`MonadIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cgi-3001.2.2.2/docs/Network-CGI.html#t:MonadIO) (if that's possible).

Comment: it will be great to see the final conversion from `ExceptT (E L) IO IO)` to `IO (Maybe (E L))`

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ Updated.

Answer (score 2):

It may worth inventing your own combinators with semantically appropriate names. Here is an example using [ExceptRT](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors-2.0.1/docs/Data-EitherR.html#t:ExceptRT) monad from [errors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors) package:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans (liftIO)
import Control.Error (rightMay, ExceptRT, runExceptT, runExceptRT, succeedT)

runE :: Functor m => ExceptRT a m e -> m (Maybe a)
runE = fmap rightMay . runExceptT . runExceptRT

report :: Monad m => a -> Bool -> ExceptRT a m ()
report res False = succeedT res
report _   _     = return ()

f :: IO (Maybe (E L))
f = runE $ do
  liftIO foo >>= report E1
  liftIO bar >>= report E2
  liftIO baz >>= either (succeedT . E3) (liftIO . quxx)
```